# Table with figure (include caption for figure) side by side.

Tags: tables, floats

I want to create a table with image on side by side. The problem I encountered is the alignment of the table. Can anyone fix the code to make the Lambda_1 and Lambda_2 become the caption for each figure accordingly? And if i don't include the & beside `1.~Real unequal eigenvalues of same sign &` 
 Then the left border of the table will not be connecting to the title border. I know the problem is with `\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|XX|}`. Can somehelp give me guide to change the code to make a better alignment? I want to change the column of the figure to 1, and include the figure side by side instead of 2 columns. 

 I insisted to use tabularx is because i did not want the table to move over the margin of my document.

```
\begin{table} [H]
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|XX|}
\hline
    \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{Collection of Figures of 2D Phase Portraits} \\ \hline 
    1.~Real unequal eigenvalues of same sign & \\ 
        \includegraphics[height=1.8in]{2D/rup.png}        $\lambda_1 > \lambda_2 > 0$ & \includegraphics[height=1.8in]{2D/run.png}$\lambda_1 > \lambda_2 < 0$  \\ 
\hline
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's really no need for a `tabularx` for just one column; a simple `tabular` can be used instead. I used the `subfigure` environment from `subcaption` and the features from [`booktabs`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/booktabs) (without the vertical rules fot the table):

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article} 
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx} 
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document} 

\begin{table}[H]
\begin{tabular}{l}
\toprule
\multicolumn{1}{c}{Collection of Figures of 2D Phase Portraits} \\ 
\midrule 
1.~Real unequal eigenvalues of same sign  \\ 
\begin{subfigure}{\dimexpr.5\linewidth-2\fboxsep\relax}
  \centering
  \includegraphics[height=1.8in]{2D/rup.png}
  \caption{$\lambda_1 > \lambda_2 > 0$}
\end{subfigure}\hfill%  
\begin{subfigure}{\dimexpr.5\linewidth-2\fboxsep\relax}
  \centering
  \includegraphics[height=1.8in]{2D/run.png}
  \caption{$\lambda_1 > \lambda_2 < 0$}
\end{subfigure} \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table} 

\end{document}
```

[image]

If captions don't require numbering for cross-referencing, one can simply use minipages:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article} 
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx} 
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document} 

\begin{table}[H]
\begin{tabular}{l}
\toprule
\multicolumn{1}{c}{Collection of Figures of 2D Phase Portraits} \\ 
\midrule 
1.~Real unequal eigenvalues of same sign  \\ 
\begin{minipage}{\dimexpr.5\linewidth-2\fboxsep\relax}
  \centering
  \includegraphics[height=1.8in]{2D/rup.png}\par
  $\lambda_1 > \lambda_2 > 0$
\end{minipage}%  
\begin{minipage}{\dimexpr.5\linewidth-2\fboxsep\relax}
  \centering
  \includegraphics[height=1.8in]{2D/run.png}\par
  $\lambda_1 > \lambda_2 < 0$
\end{minipage} \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table} 

\end{document}
```

[image]

The `demo` option for `graphicx` simply replaces actual figures with black rectangles; do *not* use that option in your actual document.

Comment: is it possible to change the column to only single column and place the figure side by side?

Comment: I've tried to use subfloat, \subfloat[a]{\includegraphics[height=1.8in]{2D/rup.png}}, but there is an error "No counter 'subtable@save' defined. \end{tabularx}". I do not know what's gone wrong.

Comment: @AndrewOoi  please see the second code in my updated answer. Something like that? Do you want the captions to be numbered?

Comment: Thanks @Gonzalo Medina, the answer helped me. But i found that the spacing between the image and the caption is kinda far, is it possible to shorten the spacing between them? and is it possible to align the '1.~Real unequal eigenvalues of same sign' to the left?

Comment: @AndrewOoi which of the two codes of my recently updated answer are you using?

Comment: The 2nd one is used. Actually i prefer the first one as there is border to cover them, but it seems like it is unable to align '1.~Real unequal eigenvalues of same sign' only in single line (for first one)

Comment: @AndrewOoi Sorry. I am confused. I updated my answer, please let ne know with this new version, which code do you like more and what features are still missing?

Comment: The code that i am using is '\begin{subfigure}{\dimexpr.5\linewidth-2\fboxsep\relax}
  \centering
  \includegraphics[height=1.8in]{2D/rup.png}'. But i want the '1.~Real unequal eigenvalues of same sign' to be aligned on the left. Not the title of the table.

Comment: @AndrewOoi Please see my updated answer. I hope this time the result id the desired one :)

Comment: Thanks. The updated is the one i desired. But when I try to change all the \toprule, \midrule and \bottomrule to \hline (as i want border line). The caption seems like overlapping with the bottom \hline.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/13641/discussion-between-gonzalo-medina-and-andrew-ooi)

Comment: I've solved the problem. Thanks alot for your help. ^.^

Comment: @AndrewOoi Ah, OK. You're welcome!